# ASP.NET Core 2.0 bundle CDN

Tags: asp.net-core, gulp, bundle, cdn

Before we could use bundles like:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bootstrapjs", "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js").Include(
                  "~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"));
```

How do I do this, for CDN paths now?
I know I can use gulp and so on, but I'm looking for at simple way to have a specific place to update all references to packages that I do not use on every page, like a calendar or a datepicker.

Before I had something like "@Scripts.Render("~/datepickerjs")" whenever I needed a datepicker, and I just updated the versionnumber in my bundleconfig.

I seems quiet like much work to update this every place I use it.

Comment: [Bundling and minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core now uses the `<environment>` tag to differentiate when to load which scripts. This is actually far superior, as you can have many different variations for virtually any number of different environments, instead of just a simple boolean toggle of optimize or not.

If you want some of the similarity of being able to load a "bundle" of scripts, you can simply create a partial view that houses the scripts you want to include together as a set. Then, simply reference this partial where you need to drop them.